# Is it possible to smooth button corners in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need smooth corners for my button. Is it possible to get that for `TSpeedButton`?

Comment: Buy the TMS component. Then you can get on with some real work.

Comment: The TMS buttons are very nice looking.

Comment: If you feel confortable at writing component, The short answer is roll your own. TSpeedButton's source code is available as a starting point.

Comment: I really don't recommend beginners try to modify TSpeedButton. I actually made a TSpeedButton with rounded corners, but the source code belongs to a past employer and the VCL code it is based on is also  not open source so I can not share it.

Answer (score 1):

I used the [TJvXPButton](http://help.delphi-jedi.org/item.php?Id=172145) (built into [Jedi JVCL](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/)) for that purpose. It has rounded corners, it's free, it looks great, and it's the same on all versions of windows, with themes on and with themes off.  In apps where I don't need the whole JVCL, I have isolated it into only 5 files, which is easy to add to any project.

If you wanted to add this to TSpeedButton you will run into the problem that TSpeedButton has been specifically designed to make your owner-draw job difficult. It is designed to draw Win 3.1 style "edges" when themes are off, and to use the XP/Vista/Win7 themes, when themes are turned on on the PC.  You can owner-draw a Speed button, but a nice smooth round cornered button is more difficult than you might think, thus the suggestion of the Jedi JVCL XP Button control (TJvXPButton).

Answer (score 0):

well, since the TSpeedButton has its own focused border. it is really impossible.
I suggest to use the rzBMPButton on RaizeComponent pack. There you can do whatever you do to the button. you just have to draw Bitmap Button with soft edge.

Comment: This one is commercial.  So, buy TMS, buy Raize, buy developer express, these are decent options, if you can spend some money. If you can't there are also lots of free options.

Comment: who know's he might interested in it.

Comment: I didn't say anybody would not want it because it's commercial, I would however suggest that you mention it yourself whenever you mention acquiring something, that it's commercial. It's courteous.